# Two polynomials generating $\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $\beta$ be the following involution (=automorphism of order two)
on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$: $\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.
Denote the set of symmetric elements w.r.t. $\beta$ by $S_{\beta}$,
and the set of skew-symmetric elements w.r.t. $\beta$ by $K_{\beta}$.

It is not difficult to see that if $s \in S_{\beta}$, then $s= a_{2n}y^{2n}+a_{2n-2}y^{2n-2}+\cdots+a_2y^2+a_0$, 
where $a_{2n},a_{2n-2},\ldots,a_2,a_0 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$,
while if $k \in K_{\beta}$, then $a_{2n+1}y^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}y^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_3y^3+a_1y$, 
where $a_{2n+1},a_{2n-1},\ldots,a_3,a_1 \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Let $s_1,s_2 \in S_{\beta}=\mathbb{C}[x,y^2]$ satisfy:
**(1)** Each of $s_1,s_2$ is of (total) degree $\geq 1$.
**(2)** $s_1,s_2$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$. 
**(3)** $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$.

For example: $s_1=x, s_2=xy^2$.

> Is it possible to find a general form of such a pair $s_1,s_2$?

**Remarks:** **(i)** If I am not wrong, if we replace condition $(3)$ to $\mathbb{C}[s_1,s_2]=\mathbb{C}[x,y^2]$, then the answer is as follows: Define $h: (x,y) \mapsto (x,y^2)$. Then a general form for such a pair $s_1,s_2$ is $s_1=(hg)(x),
s_2=(hg)(y)$ where $g$ is an *arbitrary* automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

**(ii)** Denote the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, the [Cremona group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_group), by $C$. If my argument in $(1)$ is correct, then perhaps an analog argument will solve my question as follows: Define $h: (x,y) \mapsto (x,y^2)$
($h$ is extended to the field of fractions). Then a general form for $s_1,s_2$ is $s_1=(hg)(x),
s_2=(hg)(y)$ where $g$ is an *appropriate* automorphism of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

**(iii)** If my argument in $(2)$ is correct, then I would like to know how to describe $g \in C$; I think that an answer can be found in one of the references in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253481/finding-all-automorphisms-of-mathbbcx-y), but I am not sure if I fully understand it.

**(iv)** Notice that not all elements of $C$ will be relevant to my question, since $s_1,s_2$ are assumed to be polynomials; for example, $C \ni g: (x,y) \mapsto (\frac 1x ,y)$ would yield $s_1=\frac 1x \notin \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and
$s_2=y^2$. (Or perhaps we should allow other options for $h$, for example,
$h: (x,y) \mapsto (x, \frac{1}{y^2})$ and then we can take *arbitrary* $g \in C$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why does $\beta$ play a role? Aren't you asking for $s_1,s_2\in\mathbb{C}[x,u]$, satisfying 1),2) and 3) with $y^2$ replaced by $u$?

Comment: I guess you are right; do you know an answer to my question? The reason I mentioned $\beta$ is because I am also interested in the same question with $\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ instead of $\beta$, but I wanted first to concentrate on $\beta$ hoping it is slightly easier to deal with than $\alpha$.

Comment: I am not aware of any simple answer to it. Birational generators are notoriously difficult to find. There might be some answer using resultants  (of $s_1-a, s_2-b$ for general $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Please, could you elaborate a little your idea concerning resultants?

Comment: $s_1,s_2$ form birational generators if and only if for general $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, $s_1-a,s_2-b$ have exactly one common zero. Resultants help you calculate the common zeroes of $s_1-a, s_2-b$, so may be something can be done.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I do not know why your first claim is true; it sounds a very nice condition- does it appear in a published paper? (BTW, I am familiar with resultants).

Comment: First statement is standard and elementary. Need a little geometry.

Comment: I am afraid I even do not understand your first statement (let alone prove it): Take $u=xy$ and $v=y$ (they are not symmetric w.r.t. $\beta$, but I guess your statement was for arbitrary two birational generators). Obviously, $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, but $u$ and $v$ have infinitely many common zeros: $\{(c,0)\}_{c \in \mathbb{C}}$; what am I missing? (perhaps you meant common irreducible factor?).

Comment: (Having one common irreducible factor is not a correct condition, since $x$ and $y$ do not have a common irreducible factor, but they are birational generators of course..)

Comment: Perhaps you meant considering $u=u(x,y),v=v(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ as polynomials in one variable, namely, as elements of $L(y)$, where $L=\mathbb{C}(x)$? Then $xy$ and $y$ indeed have only one common zero: $y=0$.

Comment: I guess that you have meant something similar to the results appearing, for example,  in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.3752.pdf ?

Comment: @Mohan, Concerning $u=xy$ and $v=y$: If we take $a=0,b=1$, then $u-a=xy-0=xy$ and $v-b=y-1$ indeed have one common zero which is $(0,1)$. So I guess that in your claim you meant that there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $s_1-a$ and $s_2-b$ have exactly one common zero.