# Concerning $\mathbb{C}(f,g)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $f=f(x,y),g=g(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, each of degree $\geq 1$, and $f,g$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$ (= their Jacobian $\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\{0\}$).

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299842/a-sufficient-condition-for-two-bivariate-polynomials-to-generate-mathbbcx-y) I have asked for a sufficient (and necessary) condition for $k(f,g)=k(x,y)$.

> How to apply Jeremy Blanc's answer in the following two specific cases: $f=ax+by, g=cx+dy$, $ad-bc \neq 0$;
>   $f=ux, g=vy+H(x)$, $uv \neq 0$, $H(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Another answer to the above question can be found in the comments to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772853/two-polynomials-generating-mathbbcx-y2) question; it would be nice if someone could help me in understanding and proving the claim in the comments that says:

> " $s_1,s_2$ form birational generators if and only if for general $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, $s_1−a,s_2−b$ have exactly one common zero".
>   ([Theorem 2.1](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-03/S0002-9939-97-03639-3/S0002-9939-97-03639-3.pdf) may be relevant. Perhaps the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803632/a-sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-mathbbcfx-gx-mathbbcx?rq=1) can be generalized to the two variable case).

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is rather obvious that in these cases $k(f,g) = k(x,y)$; in fact, even $k[f,g] = k[x,y]$. If you really want someone to run through the argument by @JérémyBlanc, what did you try yourself? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. On purpose I have chosen the affine and triangular generators of the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, since they are the 'simplest' examples of birational generators. Perhaps another 'simplest' example is $f=x, g=xy$. Unfortunately, I am still not familiar with algebraic geometry, so could not apply the argument of @JeremyBlanc  in specific cases.